# How to ignore or skip specific level key value in JSON.stringify | javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following javascript object and want to stringify in JSON format.
I want to skip the `(key, value)` pair at the specific level. In my case, I don't want to encode `user.id` but want to stringify `package.id`.

I am using the `replacer` of `JSON.stringify`. I know the replacer function gets every key/value pair including nested objects and array items. It is applied recursively. but I need to know is there any other way around instead of creating a new object

```js
let student = {
  id: 1, // want to skip this id.
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  isAdmin: false,
  courses: ['html', 'css', 'js'],
  package: {
    id: 121, // but need this id.
    name: "starter",
    price: 15
  },
  spouse: null
};

let str = JSON.stringify(student, function(key, value) {
  return key == 'id' ? undefined : value
});

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` in the [`replacer` function of `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will hold the original object it's called for:

> As a function, it takes two parameters: the `key` and the `value` being stringified. The object in which the key was found is provided as the `replacer`'s `this` context.

---

So you could check if any of the top-level keys exist in that object, for example, I've choisen `age` as a `student` has one, but the `package` doesn't.

Of course  this is reversable, you could also 'only remove the key if the object has (eg) a `price` key': `return !("price in this) && ...`

```js
let student = {
  id: 1, // want to skip this id.
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  isAdmin: false,
  courses: ['html', 'css', 'js'],
  package: {
    id: 121, // but need this id.
    name: "starter",
    price: 15
  },
  spouse: null
};

let str = JSON.stringify(student, function(key, value) {
  return (("age" in this) && key == 'id') ? undefined : value;
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: need to depend upon the other key values. We can digest this one but seems like not elegant solution because a student can have multiple friends.

Comment: Well if you don't want a new object this seems like the only option. NOt sure what you mean by 'multiple friends'.

Comment: How about you revert it, so you only remove the key if the object has a 'price' for example?

Comment: @SachinKumar We don't know your data. Only you can tell how to best distinguish a student from a package.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the ID just at the indicated level using only "id"

```js
const replacer = (key, value) => {
  // An array to keep track of object depth.
  let stack = [];
  return (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      let index = stack.indexOf(value);
      if (index !== -1) {
        // Circular reference found, discard key
        return;
      }
      // Store value in our stack
      stack.push(value);
    }
    // Remove 'id' keys from nested objects, but keep the root 'id' - use === 1 to get rid of the root ID
    return (key === 'id' && stack.length > 1) ? undefined : value;
  };
}

let str = JSON.stringify(student, replacer(), 2);
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script>
let student = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  isAdmin: false,
  courses: ['html', 'css', 'js'],
  package: {
    id: 121,
    name: "starter",
    price: 15
  },
  spouse: null
};

</script>
```

Comment: "*A stack […]. The current depth […] decreases as we exit their scope.*" - uh, no it doesn't? You're using that array like a `Set`, not like a stack.

Comment: @bergi ok, fine